# How to filter API values based on user input using jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, api, format

How do I change the city(q) equals London to New York, based on user input field?

Scenario: User enter the city name and temperature will be displayed according to the city name.

```
 $.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&units=metric&appid={key}', function(data){


});
```

I tried the below code. but couldn't get the expected result.

```
$(function(){

$(".submit_btn").on('click', function(){
    var city = $("#city_name").val();

    $.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&units=metric&appid={key}', function(data){

    var temp = `Temperature: ${data.main.temp} degrees Celsius`

    $(".w1").text(temp);



    });


});
});
```

Comment: ............. `${city}` .............

Comment: Nope. ${city} doesn't work

Comment: Its `${city}`  , put '`' before $ sign and '`' after end (})

Comment: The character is not being written here , it is the keyboard character under escape button (computer keyboard), its second time and its not being added , stackmaybe encrypt it or whatever...

Comment: ` this is the charecter and hope it works now.

Comment: I think you mean something like this,

$.getJSON('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=`${city}`&units=metric&appid={key}, function(data)

I found the character and hope it's the backtick. But still it's not working properly.

Comment: Yes and also same for {key}

Comment: I have the key. so, string for key works fine. but still city cannot be figured out

Comment: Then your problem is related also to html id of text box, plz provide you html code also, but for js, its calling everything right, it depends on id of text box is city_name...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211199/discussion-between-randil-tennakoon-and-mostafa-harb).

Comment: Finally it worked. I had to add backtick to either side of the whole string. just like as below,

var url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid={key}`;

adding backticks before htttp://....... & after appid={key}

Thanks for the support.

Comment: Lol great that it worked , unconsiderable solution...

Comment: Yeah, Thanks for that support. It really helped me to find the solution.

Comment: Welcome anytime mate <3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it worked as follows;

```
$.getJSON(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&units=metric&appid={key}`, function(info){

var temp = `Temperature: ${info.main.temp} degrees Celsius`

$(".w1").text(temp);
});
```

Solution: Add backticks (`) to either side of the URL.